# apache RedirectMatch on help.ubuntu.com not redirecting in all cases

Tags: apache2

For 20.04 the Ubuntu serverguide has moved to a new location. Redirects have been added to the .htaccess file. However, they are not working for all URLs.

Note that the related parts of help.ubuntu.com are published from the master launchpad branch only once per day. The objective is to get this right, as I obviously didn't yesterday.

Working example:

https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html.fr

goes to:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs

Not working example:

https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html

returns 404 Not Found.

The relevant portion of the .htaccess file:

```
# For 20.04, and likely onwards, the serveguide has moved.
# Don't try to be too clever, just force the base page and drop the rest.
#
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.html)\..* https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.pdf)\..* https://assets.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server-guide
```

It seems to need the language extension to work.
Will this work?

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.html) https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.pdf) https://assets.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server-guide
```

I do not have a way to test this on my test server, and would like to get it right in the next publication.

EDIT: By deleting the "start of line" part of the expression, it turns out that I can debug this on my test server, where the location is several sub-directories in. With Muru's testing with the answer and my own testing, there is confidence in the solution.

References:
https://help.ubuntu.com/
https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-doc/help.ubuntu.com/help.ubuntu.com
https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-doc/help.ubuntu.com/help.ubuntu.com/view/head:/.htaccess
[Apache web server - how to strip language extentions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152720/apache-web-server-how-to-strip-language-extentions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) (and [`AliasMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch)), the regex is matched against the URL. It doesn't have to match the whole of the URL, unless anchored to do so using `^` and `$`. So, yes, your suggestion:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.html) https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.pdf) https://assets.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server-guide
```

will match  both `/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html.fr` and `/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html`. It will also match `/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html.frfoobar`, but then agin, the original version did as well.

It's not that difficult to test if you have Docker installed:

1. Get the docker image and the Apache conf:

   ```
   docker run --rm httpd:2.4-alpine cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf
   ```
2. Edit `my-httpd.conf` to have `AllowOveride All` in the `<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">` block
3. Create your htaccess files:

   ```
   mkdir foo
   cat > foo/.htaccess <<EOF
   RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.html) https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
   RedirectMatch permanent ^/(stable|lts|20\.04)/(serverguide/.+\.pdf) https://assets.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server-guide
   EOF
   ```
4. Create some test cases:

   ```
   cat > urls <<EOF
   localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html.fr
   localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html
   localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf
   localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf.fr
   localhost:8080/foo/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.htmlbar
   EOF
   ```
5. Run apache:

   ```
   docker run -d --name apache -p 8080:80 -v $PWD/my-httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -v $PWD/foo:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4-alpine
   ```
6. Test your URLs against this local apache server:

   ```
   % xargs -ta urls  -n1 curl -sI
   curl -sI localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html.fr
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 15:58:34 GMT
   Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
   Location: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

   curl -sI localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.html
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 15:58:34 GMT
   Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
   Location: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

   curl -sI localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 15:58:34 GMT
   Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
   Location: https://assets.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server-guide
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

   curl -sI localhost:8080/20.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf.fr
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 15:58:34 GMT
   Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
   Location: https://assets.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server-guide
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

   curl -sI localhost:8080/foo/20.04/serverguide/remote-administration.htmlbar
   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
   Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 15:58:34 GMT
   Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   ```

Comment: Thank you. It turns out I can test on my server, but because my test publication site is buried down a few sub-directories, i had to delete the start of line part of the expression. For the final solution, I also deleted the braces for the sub-pattern definition, because it isn't used. The solution should be live sometime after noon UTC tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, deleting the braces ends up with some failure scenarios.

Comment: @Doug which parentheses? The ones around `stable|lts|20.04` have to be kept

Comment: Yes, I know that know. Thanks.

Comment: Follow up: All seems O.K. now.